# Firefox and crispEdges makes elements increase in size

Tags: css, svg

I use the css property `shape-rendering: crispEdges` to prevent aliasing rectangular shapes. This gives rects a nice, crisp feel in Chrome and Safari.

In Firefox 25 on OSX though, using `shape-rendering: crispEdges` draws one, long connected block w/o the 1px spacing we use between bars. Basically, it looks like the actual SVG container must align on a 1/2 px step (not just the elements inside of it). There isn't a way to guarentee this with a fluid layout that uses width percentages.

Here's an example that illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/dlite/AL2BH/1/.

Is there a workaround to get Chrome-like `crispEdges` behavior in Firefox 25 on OSX?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Win8/Firefox 25 - behavior matches Chrome.

Comment: Michael - sorry, I didn't specify I'm running OSX. I updated the question w/this info. I also tried adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to each SVG element w/no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/dlite/AL2BH/2/